# containable and extra id field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Suppose I have a tipical **Post** `belongsTo` **User** `belongsTo` **Group** scenario

suppose I want to filter the **Posts** using some conditions and I want to know how many distinct groups are involved (I just need the list of `group_id`)

I did something like

```
$this->Post->find(
    'all'
    array(
        'fields' => array('DISTINCT User.group_id'),
        'conditions' => array ( ... ), // here go my search criteria about posts
        'contain' => array('User')
    )
);
```

I expected a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT User.group_id FROM posts AS Post LEFT JOIN users AS USER ON ...
```

But when using `contains` cake introduce an extra field so the query becomes

```
SELECT DISTINCT User.group_id, User.id FROM posts AS Post LEFT JOIN users AS USER ON ...
```

and I don't get the expected result.

I solved using manual joins, but is there any way to force cake not to add that `id` field for the contained table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want by turning off `$autoFields` on the Containable behavior.

```
$this->Post->Behaviors->load('Containable', array('autoFields' => false));
```

See the book for more info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I still don't like the fact that I have to set the value of `autoFields` when loading the behavior and I can't set it in my find options but it's much better than using manual joins